# Lsi MegaRaid sas 9271-8i raid-0 crash

Tags: windows, lsi, megaraid, raid0

I have 8 hhd , all of it have RAID-0. Yesterday one disk change status to configurate good, it's disk with OS. And now I can't start my server , import foreign configuration not work, and I can not discard cache it's not work too. How to reestablish server work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RAID 0 recovery](https://serverfault.com/questions/64479/raid-0-recovery)

Answer (score 5):

You wipe and rebuild - you chose R0, by doing so you made the conscious decision that your data doesn't matter, at all, as you must have a ready-to-go mitigation right to hand. Well do that.